# Какой тег для managed Field в drupal?

Tags: php, drupal

Добавил я пользователю дополнительное поле. Допустим company_name
А как к нему теперь обратиться?
К имени пользователя [user:name] код - [user:uid]
имя сайта - [site:name]
а как обращаться к пользовательским дополнительным полям?
[field:company_name] не работает

Answer (score 0):

установить плагин token и собственно в help ссылки будут
[user:field_company_name:value]